# Why I am getting InvalidOperationException: Cannot override the 'href' attribute for <a>. An <a> with a specified 'href'

Tags: razor

Why I am getting ?

> InvalidOperationException: Cannot override the 'href' attribute for
> . An  with a specified 'href' must not have attributes starting
> with 'asp-route-' or an 'asp-action', 'asp-controller', 'asp-area',
> 'asp-route', 'asp-protocol', 'asp-host', 'asp-fragment', 'asp-page' or
> 'asp-page-handler' attribute.

```
<li class="page-item"><a asp-page="index"  class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

The '[Anchor Tag Helper in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-7.0)' triggers an error when trying to generate an `href` for an anchor element when an `href` attribute is manually added to the anchor element in addition to the `asp-` prefixed attributes.

Here's a [reference](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/tag-helpers/anchor-tag-helper) to the error you're getting:

> The anchor tag helper's role is to generate an href attribute from the parameter values passed to its custom attributes. Therefore, if you try to add an href attribute to the anchor tag helper as well as values to the custom attributes, an exception will be raised.

Remove the `href="#"` attribute or remove the `asp-` prefixed attributes  from the anchor element. `href` and `asp-` prefixed attributes cannot coexist.

```
<li class="page-item"><a asp-page="index" class="page-link">3</a></li>
```

or

```
<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
```